# Importing Android project in ECLIPSE issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I am importing a project into eclipse...But when i go to LAYOUT folder the "GRAPHIC LAYOUT DESIGN" is missing. 
Please help..
Please see the attached SCREEN SHOT[image]

Comment: what is your android platform/API level? Have you tried changing that value and see what happens?

Comment: yes i have tried but still not getting it :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Eclipse doesn't "get" the XML type from the plain file. To force it to open with the layout editor try right clicking on the .xml then "Open With...", then "Android Layout Editor".

Comment: Do you have any SDKs installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `SDK level/version` from the drop-down menu.